# How do I enable dragging files to applications minimised to Ubuntu Dock in 17.10?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, drag-and-drop

I have upgraded to 17.10 but I am frustrated that I am unable to drag a file say, from Files to a text editor that is minimised. In older versions I was able to drag it to the sidebar, hover over the application and it would open. Is there a way to get this to work in 17.10?

Answer (score 9):

As an alternative, if you enable top left hotcorner for activities, drag a file there, then drag it above the application, wait for it to activate, drop your file

You can enable it with:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell enable-hot-corners true
```

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately [this feature](https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues/49) is not yet implemented in [Dash to Dock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/) extension (Ubuntu dock, the sidebar in Ubuntu 17.10 onwards, is a fork of Dash to Dock). According to the developer of the extension

> There is one mayor [sic] stopping thing: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=696321. Support has to be provided upstream first. I did try patching gnome-shell with the patch attached to that bug and got a proof of concept, but can't go on without upstream support.
>
> I have investigated the option of showing the application windows on drag and drop, so that at least you can release the item on an already opened windows. This is technically possible - right now in gnome-shell this [can be done going throw [sic] the activities button](https://askubuntu.com/a/1073266/480481) but it's not very handy.